# Move UITableViewCell from one section to another programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to move a UITableViewCell from section `0` to section `1`, without using

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

In [Clear](http://realmacsoftware.com/clear), when you complete a task, instead of deleting and inserting, it simply moves onto of the other ones and onto the bottom.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you review the docs for `UITableView`? You will find methods to move rows if you have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
 [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This should work across sections.

(Note: I took this from the [Moving Tableviewcells Cookbook](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture), which describes how to do this with user interaction)

Comment: Is there any way to add a transition? It simply jumps to the new indexPath.

Comment: Haven't tried this on my own but maybe wrapping it in begin and end updates (table view methode) will animate it. Otherwise you could try to subclass or use a costum animation like they do it in the related link but instead of making it follow your touch set a path programmatically. I think you should be able to do this straight foward.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out! Thanks!